# How does Cucumber DSL work?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, dsl, internal

Let's take:

```
When /^(?:|I )fill in the following:$/ do |fields|
  fields.rows_hash.each do |name, value|
    When %{I fill in "#{name}" with "#{value}"}
  end
end
```

With my rudimentary Ruby knowledge, I was thinking that `When` is a method call that takes a regular expression and a block.

But then, I am also thinking that this is a definition, and not a method call, but then how is it achieved? How can `When` define something?

Comment: What do you mean by “this is a definition, and not a method call”?

Comment: I mean I'm thinking that `When ... do ... end` is a definition in some way, because in *line 3*, we can call it using a string.

Comment: You have me completely confused :) What’s wrong with calling a method in line 3? Take a look at how they implemented [`World`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb#L49). The `When` is to be defined in the same way somewhere in _Gherkin_ implementation.

Comment: When is a method that takes some arguments, and optionally a block. Remember that in Ruby, method arguments can be of any type and blocks can be optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is the following (code taken from [here](https://github.com/engineyard/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_dsl.rb)):

```
def register_rb_step_definition(regexp, symbol = nil, options = {}, &proc)
  proc_or_sym = symbol || proc
  RbDsl.register_rb_step_definition(regexp, proc_or_sym, options)
end
```

`When`, `Given`, `Then` are an alias to `register_rb_step_definition`.
You pass a regular expression as an argument, and a block.

Each step definition is *registered* with the regular expression and the block. When the test is executed, cucumber looks in the previously registered steps and if any regular expression matches it executes the block associated to that regular expression.